# Count the numbers in which the product of the digits is 48 (1 not allowed)

Tags: combinatorics, contest-math

> Count the numbers in which the product of the digits is 48 (1 not allowed as digit).

**Proposed solution:** I addressed the problem by brute force, first noticing that
$$48=2^4\times 3.$$

Then I found the possible groups of digits to be permuted for each number: (1) 2,2,2,2,3; (2) 2,2,2,6; (3) 4,2,2,3; (4) 4,2,6; (5) 4,4,3; (6) 8,2,3; (7) 8,6.

By adding the permutations with repetition for each case, I've found 38 possible numbers. Which agrees with the answer provided in the source.

**My problem:** I found this solution is not elegant and I'm wondering if there is a better way to address problems like these. By brute force it is easy to undercount terms (as I did as first solving the problem). Any help?

Comment: I think there is no better way. I may be wrong.

Answer (score 3):

> Not a 'real' answer, but it was too big for a comment. I think that you're looking for a solution without using a calculator or PC but maybe this gives some insight. I did only a quick search with the following bound: $1\le\text{n}\le10^7$.

I wrote and ran some [Mathematica](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wolfram_Mathematica)-code:

```
In[1]:=Clear["Global`*"];
ParallelTable[
  If[TrueQ[Product[
       Part[IntegerDigits[n], k], {k, 1, 1 + Floor[Log10[n]]}] == 48 &&
      MemberQ[IntegerDigits[n], 1] == False], n, Nothing], {n, 1, 
   10^7}] //. {} -> Nothing
```

Running the code gives:

```
Out[1]={68, 86, 238, 246, 264, 283, 328, 344, 382, 426, 434, 443, 462, 624, 
642, 823, 832, 2226, 2234, 2243, 2262, 2324, 2342, 2423, 2432, 2622, 
3224, 3242, 3422, 4223, 4232, 4322, 6222, 22223, 22232, 22322, 23222, 
32222}
```

So, the sum of the numbers is given by $179141$. I found that using:

```
In[2]:=Clear["Global`*"];
Total[ParallelTable[
   If[TrueQ[
     Product[Part[IntegerDigits[n], k], {k, 1, 
         1 + Floor[Log10[n]]}] == 48 && 
      MemberQ[IntegerDigits[n], 1] == False], n, Nothing], {n, 1, 
    10^7}] //. {} -> Nothing]

Out[2]=179141
```

Answer (score 3):

There isn't a much better way, no. There are better ways for calculating the number of ordered factorizations but those will include factorizations with factors that aren't single digits.

If $a_n = $ the number of ordered factorizations of $n$ then we have two identities:

1. $a_n = \sum a_d$ over all factors $d$ of $n$ not including $d = n$.
2. $a_{p^k} = 2^{k - 1}$ when $p$ is a prime.

See http://oeis.org/A074206 for references/additional formulae/etc.

So using this we have

\begin{align}
a_{48} &= a_1 + a_2 + a_3 + a_4 + a_6 + a_8 + a_{12} + a_{16} + a_{24} \\
&= 1 + 1 + 1 + 2 + a_6 + 4 + a_{12} + 8 + a_{24} \\
&= 17 + a_6 + a_{12} + a_{24} \\
&= 17 + (a_1 + a_2 + a_3) + ([a_1 + a_2 + a_3] + a_4 + a_6) \\
&\quad\qquad+ ([a_1 + a_2 + a_3 + a_4 + a_6] + a_8 + a_{12}) \\
&= 17 + 3 + (3 + 2 + 3) + (8 + 4 + 8) \\
&= 48
\end{align}

So there are 48 total ordered factorizations. But we know this is overcounting because it includes factorizations which are permutations of $2,24$ and $2,2,12$ and $4,12$ and $3,16$. So that's an additional $2 + 3 + 2 + 2 = 10$.

So there are $48 - 10 = 38$ ordered factorizations where no factor is larger than $9$.

Was this easier than calculating the number $38$ directly? Probably not. But hopefully it's still useful to someone.

Comment: The nice thing about this approach is that you won't overlook a factorization.